# Anatomically Correct Great Maccao

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, evolution, video-games

so this is a Great Maccao from Monster Hunter: Generation

[image]

a feathered raptor like creature that can stand on its tail, carrying its whole body up in the air for sometimes

I heard kangaroo can do that, but but not like this guy

**so how can it stand on its tail without any support from its legs, allowing it to balance itself on its tail with its legs in the air?**

Comment: Previous knowledge of worlds while helping to clarify an intent, shouldn't be the only descriptor. More information on how your creature works such as, How long must they stand on the tail, what actions must they be able to perform while tail only, or why using the tail is important to the species would help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about an existing work of fiction as opposed to creating a new fictional world.

Comment: When it comes to the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609), the devil is in the details - especially when it conflicts with a basic rule of the site, [we don't answer questions about 3rd party or commercial universes](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7334/40609). Note that you basically answered your own question: follow the evolution of kangaroos to their extreme.